# Application.Inputbox (Types) in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Any one please tell me, how to allow to user have to enter only text in input box.I want to use **Application.Inputbox** command in vba code.

Comment: Why not just use the regular input box? It is already text-only.

Comment: @Coleman - Regular input box is not allow to select the data in excel but application.inputbox command allows the user to select the data in excel as input.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
Sub GiveMeData()
    Dim s As String
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Type some text: ", Type:=2)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Using this `Type` can be a valuable surrogate for other types because you can parse the string to test for compliance with format requirements.

Comment: For anybody who cares to know: the [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx) for `Application.InputBox` is text (Type:=2). So, you may actually choose to omit that.